# Links VERY slow

Tags: google-chrome, 17.10, url

I reinstalled Ubuntu 17.10 a few days ago. Since then, clicking on any link outside of Chrome (e.g. Thunderbird, Nautilus PDF file, Slack, etc.) takes several seconds to open in Chrome, and it seems to kill Chrome and show only the new link as a tab. I need to hit the "Restore" button in Chrome to get my old open tabs back.

Any ideas?